# DRM mode_set not called for second DSI panel

Tags: linux, framebuffer, drm, android-drm

I have two DSI bridges connected to my android module that has 2 DSI ports. Each panel works well if I do not set two panels in the device tree. But, when both displays are declared, only the primary works. For the secondary, the mode_set callback from the drm_bridge_func. That is the only difference I can find, and I do not why it does not get called. Or maybe should I call it manually somehow?